# Can't connect my SQL Server base to Java app on NetBeans

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

I have installed NetBeans IDE 12.3 on Lubuntu and SQL Server thanks to the microsoft documentation.
I have created my database using the command line tool `sqlcmd` (I don't have a GUI for sql server like you have on windows).

In the netbeans interface, I connected my sql server base to my java project, I see the base, I see the tables. Using the SQL tool of netbeans I can request them, add/delete entries etc. no problem.

But I would like to make request in the java code itself, not in the sql tool of netbeans. The documentation says I should create a Connection object, but can't I just use the connection I created through the graphical netbeans interface ?

I get this error: `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\db:1433;databaseName=ConservatoireDB`

Here is the code in `main`:

```
ResultSet resultSet = null;

try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\db:1433;databaseName=ConservatoireDB");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();) {

    // Create and execute a SELECT SQL statement.
    String selectSql = "select * from salle";
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectSql);

    // Print results from select statement
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        System.out.println(resultSet.getString(2) + " " + resultSet.getString(3));
    }
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

By the way, my project is a graphical app using Swing library.

Comment: you need jdbc driver jar in the  lib folder or build path

Comment: i'm sorry but how do I do this ?

Comment: i don't have a library tab in project properties